# I want to print a error message if a String variable contains numbers

Tags: java, string, loops, integer, message

I am doing a exercise where i need to accept numbers in a string variable and divide them with 10, and i am not allowed to use .nextInt(); or Integer.ParseInt(); I want to print out an error message if a String variable contain letters. Right now the error message works if i only enter letters in the string variable but if i mix it up with letters and numbers the error message does not work. What can i do to solve this problem.

Code so far:

import java.util.regex.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise8 {

```
private static Scanner input;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter some numbers");
    
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double divide = 10;
    int sum = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int j = 0;
    
    while (x < 1) {
        
        String strNumbers = input.next();
        
        if (!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", strNumbers)) {
            
            ++x;

            for (int i = strNumbers.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                
                sum += Math.pow(10, j) * (strNumbers.charAt(i) - '0');
                j++;    
            }   
            
            System.out.println("Your numbers: " + sum);
            System.out.println("Your numbers divided by 10: " + sum/divide);
        }
        
        else {
            
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try this `!strNumbers.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*");`

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to match problem described in question itself. It looks like it should be more like "I want to print a error message if a String doesn't represent a number" (instead of `number` you can use more specific numeric type like `int` or `long`, depending on what you want to handle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invert if statement and check whether `strNumbers` variable contains ONLY digits.

```
if (Pattern.matches("\\d+", strNumbers)) {
    //handle case where number is valid ...
}
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Sometimes is also useful to add a bit of guidance to the OP by including a link/reference to a tutorial or doc. In this case, I'd encourage him to read how regex works and common patterns. Otherwise, this is just solving his homework.